# What (simple) program can I use to monitor my internet usage

Tags: windows, networking, internet, monitoring

I want to know what programs are using XXX bandwidth?

For example...if Firefox is downloading 500kbps, I want to know that.
And if Google Installer is downloading...I want to know that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NetLimiter Monitor](http://netlimiter.com) can do this and much more.

[image]

NetLimiter Monitor is freeware.

Comment: While it looks cool, it turns to be a crippled version of its shareware counterpart that has more features. Are there any truly freeware alternatives to this, that can also do ip/port-based traffic shaping and prioritization?

Comment: I know monitor is a crippled version, but the monitoring component is all this particular user needs. Maybe traffic shaper XP is a better fit for you: http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html

Comment: That one is a crippled version as well. And it looks like it doesn't include flexible prioritization.

Comment: Ah well, it's free, I wouldn't expect too much of it.